# Facebook url is not getting in webView

Tags: android, facebook, url, webview, browser-history

I have an application with WebView. In my WebView, I will get next page URL from:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String URL)
```

and I'm saving this URL for further process. I'm also using:

```
webView.loadUrl(baseUrl)
```

By using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function, I will get the URLs loading by my WebView. But in facebook case *(page loaded as mobile view)*, I didn't get the URLs which I'm switching through facebook.

*For instance:* First I loaded facebook I got that URL, then I go to my home, then my page, then events, then other people profile, pages etc. I didn't get any of the URLs except the first one.

Comment: I quitely sure that facebook has it own hardcode url. You just need to get the Log of url inside the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String URL)` to find out.

Comment: I tried it before asking this question.